# Как получить фото от юзера через state TG

Tags: python, telegram-bot, aiogram

```
@dp.message_handler(state=bot.ppl)
async def ppl(message: types.Message, state=FSMContext):
    print('+')

@dp.message_handler(state=bot.ppl, content_types=['photo'])
async def ppl(message: types.Message, state=FSMContext):
    print('+')


await bot.ppl.set()
```

Пробовал всё,но когда отправляю фото  ничего не происходит.На state ничего не реагирует

Comment: `@dp.message_handler(state=bot.ppl, content_types=['photo'])` что-то я не уверен, что с `content_types` правильно... Попробуйте `content_types=types.ContentType.PHOTO` или `content_types=[types.ContentType.PHOTO]`. Лучше приложите минимальный пример, чтобы те, кто захотел помочь вам, мог запустить код и повторить проблему

Comment: Хорошо, сейчас попробую

Comment: Сработало, Спасибо! >>> content_types=types.ContentType.PHOTO

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нужно тип указывать через [types.ContentType](https://github.com/aiogram/aiogram/blob/61fe788355fb5e37e3eb6526e4050e8f9f141c26/aiogram/types/message.py#L3183):

```
@dp.message_handler(state=bot.ppl, content_types=types.ContentType.PHOTO)
async def ppl(message: types.Message, state=FSMContext):
    print('+')
```